# Is d3.json slower than other methods for JSON file reads?

Tags: json, performance, d3.js, file-read

So I have a .json file of around 33 MB. I am using d3.json() to read the file, but it takes significant time (around 1.5-2 seconds), which is a lot since I need to updating my parameters multiple times (to render visualizations using d3 itself).

(I only need to read the file once though, but I haven't figured out a way to maintain it as a global variable, if that's even a good idea.)

Any suggestions? Should I be setting up a backend for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I loaded up the data as a JS variable, seems to work for my purpose.